# Rails Many To Many, seed records with extra information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding

I'm trying to seed the following data structure:

```
class Company
    has_many :user_roles 
    has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end

class User 
    has_many :user_roles 
    has_many :companies, through: :user_roles
end

class UserRole 
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :company
end
```

Besides the fields user_id and company_id, the UserRoles tables also has the field "role" that says whether the user is a "member" or a "admin to a given company.

I'm trying to seed the tables as follows:

```
u1 = User.create(name: 'Tester 1')
u2 = User.create(name: 'Tester 2')

e1 = Company.create(name: 'Company 1')
e2 = Company.create(name: 'Company 2')

ur1 = UserRole.create(role: 'admin', user_id: 2, company_id: 1)
ur2 = UserRole.create(role: 'member', user_id: 3, company_id: 1)
ur3 = UserRole.create(role: 'admin', user_id: 3, company_id: 2)
```

But when I try to verify, *the UserRole table is always empty and no connection is created between the tables*.
If I try to add Users to the Companies directly, using

```
e1.users << [u1, u2]
e2.users << [u2]
```

Then the UserRole table shows, but I don't know how to add the 'role' information. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I try to verify, the UserRole table is always empty and no
>   connection is created between the tables.

Your `UserRole` objects are most likely not being created because the id's are not available. To be sure use `create!` instead of `create` so you get an exception (`create` will return false with no exception, that is, it fails *silently*) and identify the error:

```
ur1 = UserRole.create!(role: 'admin', user_id: 2, company_id: 1)
ur2 = UserRole.create!(role: 'member', user_id: 3, company_id: 1)
ur3 = UserRole.create!(role: 'admin', user_id: 3, company_id: 2)
```

> Then the UserRole table shows, but I don't know how to add the 'role'
>   information.

Once you created an object, you can update an attribute in several ways (check [here](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/) for more information), the most common being `=` followed by `save`:

```
e1.role = "admin"
e1.save
```

or `update`:

```
e1.update(role: "admin")
```

---

As a side note: to ensure you got no errors related with id's, use the objects you already generated (e.g. `u1`, `e1`) to assign those id's:

```
ur1 = UserRole.create!(role: 'admin', user_id: u1.id, company_id: e1.id)
ur2 = UserRole.create!(role: 'member', user_id: u2.id, company_id: e1.id)
ur3 = UserRole.create!(role: 'admin', user_id: u2.id, company_id: e2.id)
```

This way no matter which id is assigned (remember that deleting records doesn't reset the auto-numeric id in database), you will always get a valid one.

Comment: @OriginalBBQSauce Great! Glad to help! While seeding i recommend always use bang `!` methods (e.g. `create!`) to identify any error right away.